# list of built-in colors grouped by color equality

Tags: c#, colors, compareto

I'd like to compare colors but haven't got a clue where to start. I tried

```
private static int CompareColors(Color colorA, Color colorB)
{
    long resultA = colorA.A + colorA.B + colorA.G + colorA.R;
    long resultB = colorB.A + colorB.B + colorB.G + colorB.R;
    return (int)Math.Max(-1, Math.Min(1, resultA - resultB));
}
```

but all that does is compare the total 'color value' without taking into account differences in separate channels and produces a kind of dark-to-light list. so then I tried

```
private static int CompareColors(Color colorA, Color colorB)
{
    string resultA = colorA.Tostring();
    string resultB = colorB.Tostring();
    return string.Compare(resultA, resultB);
}
```

which seems to produce slightly better results but still interspersed with an oddly out-of-place bright color from time to time (particularly in the 'softer'/'lower value' colors region). (how) can I improve on that last result?

**EDIT:** thanks for all the comments, I now understand this question may need some more background for you to be able to produce meaningful responses, so I'll elaborate and hope you're still with me on answering this. this is my goal: imagine a color palette like [this one](http://images.wikia.com/secondlife/images/6/63/Color-picker.png), I'd like to represent this in a sorted list. of course the color palette is 2D and my list is 1D but I'm only working with the built-in colors that I lookup like this

```
List<Color> colors = new List<Color>();
Type colorType = typeof(Colors);
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in colorType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static))
{
    if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(Color))
    {
        colors.Add((Color)propertyInfo.GetValue(null, null));
    }
}
colors.Sort(new Comparison<Color>((colorA, colorB) => CompareColors(colorA, colorB)));
```

and with those colors I'm trying to produce a list where the colors are grouped by a kind of color equality like on the color palette. sorting by brightness is second but still important for smooth transitions between color groups.

for clarity's sake: with 'color equality' and 'color groups' I'm referring to the visually coherent color regions in the sample color palette. with 'smooth transitions' I'm referring to the regions in the color palette in between the visually coherent color regions. I'm not working with a vast variety of colors like the sample color palette features, I'm only working with the built-in colors (which appear to feature a good amount of cream-like colors).

Comment: How about summing the difference in each component? (although not sure how it'd perform when difference in red was -10, difference in blue was 10, for example). A variation of this idea could work though.

Comment: Could you start by giving us the tiniest hint of what the hell you're trying to do? (More precisely, how do you want to define your total or partial ordering?)

Comment: Another way of thinking of this, is imagining the color as a 3D coordinate. The difference between 2 colors would be the distance between the 2 points in 3D space.

Comment: What's your definition for comparison?  Is one color "less than" another color if it's closer to black?

Comment: You're "wondering why there's no such thing as a CompareTo" and yet you "haven't got a clue where to start?"  That makes sense.

Comment: If you want to sort by brightness, you should convert each color to its HSL/HSV representation, and use the L/V component as the basis for comparison (falling back on S and then H when necessary.)

Answer (score 3):

If you need arbitrary sorting, you can implement it in any way. For example:

```
private static int CompareColors(Color colorA, Color colorB)
{
  if (colorA.A > colorB.A)
    return 1;
  if (colorA.A < colorB.A)
    return -1;

  if (colorA.R > colorB.R)
    return 1;
  if (colorA.R < colorB.R)
    return -1;

  if (colorA.G > colorB.G)
    return 1;
  if (colorA.G < colorB.G)
    return -1;

  if (colorA.B > colorB.B)
    return 1;
  if (colorA.B < colorB.B)
    return -1;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks but this appears to yield the exact same results as the string comparison method